# Is it possible to send multiple values from one select option in form?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor-pages

If you select option 2 for example, I want to send both the value 2 (for the amount of books to be added) but also the Book_ID for the chosen book.

So in my method that retrieves the form I expect to get both an integer value of 2 and also an integer value for my Book_ID.

I was hoping you could do something like
`<option value=@ShoppingCartItem.Book_ID value="1" >1</option>` 
but that obviously didn't seem to work.

Below is a code snippet from my current View.

```
@foreach (Lab2.Models.ShoppingCartDetail ShoppingCartItem in Model.ShoppingcartList)
{
    <tr>
        
        <td>@ShoppingCartItem.Title</td>
        <td>@ShoppingCartItem.Author</td>
        <td>@ShoppingCartItem.Price :-</td>
        <td>@ShoppingCartItem.NumberOfBooks</td>
        <td>
            <form action="UpdateNumberOfBooks" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="NumberOfBooks" name="NumberOfBooks" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </td>

        
    </tr>
}
```

If it's possible, how should my method look that retrieves this information?

Comment: @David I have this Book_ID in my ShoppingCartItem list, so I can use "@ShoppingCartItem.Book_ID" to get that information. Maybe it's possible to use a hidden input as you said, but how should my method recieving this form look like then? I hoped I could have just two integers as inparameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add that value as an `<input>` to your form.  For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Book_ID" value="@ShoppingCartItem.Book_ID" />
```

This would include the `Book_ID` as a separate value in the same `<form>`.

> how should my method look that retrieves this information?

Presumably you have a method which receives something like this, no?:

```
public IActionResult UpdateNumberOfBooks(int numberOfBooks)
```

If that's the case, you'd just include this second value as well:

```
public IActionResult UpdateNumberOfBooks(int book_ID, int numberOfBooks)
```

Or if `NumberOfBooks` is included as part of a model, you'd add `Book_ID` to that model.  Basically, however you currently receive the one value you have now, you'd add the new value alongside it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried something similar first but didn't get it to work. Now when I tried your solution it worked just fine! Very much appreciate your help.